# i have write 3 script on html page and i want to get 3rd script tag value from the html page using the dom parser

Tags: node.js

i want to get all script tags using foreachloop

```
<script id="wiz_jd" nonce="TPwfWuzY1BHxa72M4FPOew">
    if (window['_wjdc']) {const wjd = {}; window['_wjdc'](wjd); delete window['_wjdc'];}
</script>
<script aria-hidden="true" id="WIZ-footer" nonce="TPwfWuzY1BHxa72M4FPOew">
    window.wiz_progress&&window.wiz_progress(); window.stopScanForCss&&window.stopScanForCss(); ccTick('bl');
</script>
<script nonce="TPwfWuzY1BHxa72M4FPOew">"https://video-downloads.googleusercontent.com/AMIVHOP-mMt60ID-tJNm1VGKyoIa1YPN9LU8ZW2DAp4rPWYoSad4dKdhGW2nz6odOMyCy_d6j23kjAUGjEu_lBLjCH_4FOe9GZPudazY6jl1xtPPWQ6B47-Uho1VXUKLx9tMCgwkiAwNy5Ej-Zlop2bLXohe-tOT27MgNUwlORINALQPPpsn_-qK7V_iiKRzNc-pIkxAMhcpAogccmWsUlC_IqYis4r8U8OPPdx1j9QjkF_KxRvfhmVPClxCgYEATB_gpCcEfonalZdMwm5seHcCrvf0JOBZSRmL5LBDfwJX6dWJFFTyCXM4H3WzWq7eO4-nhEyp2nVZaTBtibCKh6uuElTPXjAv0gKDTbJpkEz1UL1qwRFYKua2ZYlx7U_S4vqxc6JJjo6TkGvNJ2P_79MEx85179S7C5sbmlVlhpWbcZRKvGrg-a9SnQAy-blzFEPvofPdB1MeSjTJ0tpwjBqA0Sd-rkCFFRijrcImYXtdbsUrdi0wZ_Tt7qOs-KknKY0_RZmM5344p7Ex6hlyamIMO8znYomxea_H3_76XmTR2ljKwc6C1o0C07EYk8ToHGbp0Unl-HqOuBCAYSugrTukl68xwmfhiKyDIsNYaNblKZEQ4QLiEwLKszDA7VIqbIwty1ueIQuLKoXLhDSJNQivE5u0dvE6BjGKnu5QIjci0P-Edx14qqpJqO6yfLBnLNxKELn5cTCSzvH8GqFQpo90pjOojmJeg5HgJA3tGAO0xTB-PHyB7G8oWASkwOdCUHGpLHKZaEaC-nt2U1gGLPObeusyv_Gjowv0ceU-7EtOosuT_Lf99xdsCn4wvb-2nHCA8hhJrYXghrga1EZtRC6BOo91xgAb5R4xU1SXhf6m7ufIBoP-E1-gjvXzMSnu72H7rUhVd5JgDkm0I6vrytuAs-wg9_Ru6_oTGXksPAAGBOucsPoUZlCd7WSc8xLyp84lejQgq_43UhVkuLS1sr1Sgll1nodELEcoJ6Ecwxava2c6SYQ4gRrWFxMK60lNycvP2QtdyoGfpFJJunv70Hqft6wqPD7XOy6olCi4b9axOQSYdtfk3zc09PXeww0i9nJlnsEj6uecIwH71hs_6FhiBhCYIPpAUNeLWVZltUqYyfvMF8G8ObOSyicB9XByffDcIm2wTNCSx9Ad5U_vWM6ypnyqKMBDAQ",["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc_lUNmLooOzNM__vq2-AN6oXJzFaLm_SHRVDygy7aWRdlJWCh2j0CQlLO3rAd3cQGTOEXha3yJnlT1vlHrGwoLdtb_qGC-QCQORDuM42Goq19BQE_TuGBsCuWcvqnUVL4gprE0ZbrDKg1ZMQ2kGBePcoUFGj8xQ6dl44mkXaRuxleiQPNH3zsPb__XPAU-XjPAYC96JNAqJZ2LzMGtVFnoqnJoZheOu1VucWPqf_LHSvtIFHn9DwZUG-P6-40Q-xgOtvcIod8tTmLp-gpZlgwV_rrMdRG9JeBFMUBg--tpxRJK96AbTkvnczZe5if1QR6yo_DqyDfFnL-C9gucnbTJaaSbsh_TGPnD5y39OxOxsCfziS15FiIefFPz8NB6jHo32BHciTrdhlBWIIDCGF2PV1ljdhsjh4t2QYP6Wh4BrccXFIPdvAf68LQWpoE9ldTE9tGesIAWsCOrMwYyxOP7V9euxmVGUO1Dav9yQrNmWado9XCKFFuMNa3OGj7BNe9D-q9OZqMoashjIpnkTvj3IqnsGnphLmAPITzvTisY5fXwau4aR9SvNeHJBqr3f_HyRKoJK7m5xPjuQmyDHgZnBXGbJ8-gVGuwzCjUZBMeZ_QJUvP59nUD2uNYu_IOKEFiive7g2Y2ZU7B33AC_70xSd4sTbBK4H5Eor5PvI8jj0Je4clhgQCGHpvNL9pyzotc8Gi660QibQDoGICWFWSrmqh55iZwR2i6U3IctUjKOqmCMjmghr09IeYD_AuH8HpiPFWtdZLIVYoitOZG3HUEDP6gcM3HnK6WboEkBForCpmJv6unWFwHdl9-9lQKcRk4U2zQOROdFl1_P_s9GeUgerTzBfQ0K2Zsphx55KMzal41ll6K9Srw98viCsVWokcTr802ZHC-1XDyEvyeDCX2LGlFx1kZdIE5SR8LuravDxjLktuAS9qE-m1QIkZhXz2bwe_vHGtrSmgsiNw"</script>
```

Comment: And what have you tried to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
var scripts = dom.getElementsByTagName('script');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    values.push(scripts[i].innerHTML);
}
console.log(values);
```